# jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/%7B%7B%20url_for('app.getData')%20%7D%7D 404 (NOT FOUND)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, ajax

I want to get json from js to python script as a json and not as a string.
I am getting the above error in chrome browser's console when I write the following: 
javascript code:

```
data.push({
"start":0,
"end":10
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

 $.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "{{ url_for('app.getData') }}",
data: JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
});
```

python code:

```
@app.route('/getData', methods=["GET", "POST"])def getData():
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.json['start'])
return request.json['start']
```

Comment: Whatever templating language you are using is not replacing `url : "{{ url_for('app.getData') }}",`

Comment: What should I write to make it work?